# How to handle optional Foreign Key constraint error in One to Many relationship

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-fluent-api

I am a beginner in ASP.Net MVC 5 and currently stuck with Fluent API Issue. I have a Referral Class which can have one to many relationship with Coverletter class. Sometimes a Rererral row may exist w/o a coverletter (I think 0..*).

**Fluent API:**

```
//// one cover letter can be there in many referral request
dBModelBuilder.Entity<CoverLetter>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Referrals)
    .WithOptional(u => u.CoverLetter)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.CoverLetterId);
```

**Referral Model:**

```
public class Referral
{
    [Key]
    public int ReferralId { get; set; }
    // I added "?" to make FK Optional
    public int? CoverLetterId { get; set; }
    public virtual CoverLetter CoverLetter { get; set; }
}
```

**ReferralViewModel:**

```
public class ReferralViewModel
{
    public int ReferralViewModelId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cover Letter")]
    public int CoverLetterId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CoverLetter> CoverLetters { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ReferralViewModel viewModel)
{
    var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var referral = new Referral
    {
        CoverLetterId = viewModel.CoverLetterId
    };
   // I get exception here
    _context.Referrals.Add(referral);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("ReferralCenter");
}
```

**Issue**
When I do not select any coverletter from UI then CoverLetter ID comes as 0 from my viewModel. And I think since in DB there is no coverletter with ID 0 I am getting DB Contraint Exception.

Exception:

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.Referrals_dbo.CoverLetters_CoverLetterId\". The conflict
>   occurred in database \"aspnet-Bridge-20170730012232\", table
>   \"dbo.CoverLetters\", column 'CoverLetterId'.\r\nThe statement has
>   been terminated."}

**To make FK Optional I did two steps**

a. Added "?" in the Model Property

b. Added "HasOptional" in Fluent API.

### Fix:

When ever I do not select any CoverlLetter then on form submission I want the CoverLetter ID as **NULL** and not Zero.

Comment: Your `CoverLetterId` property in the view model needs to be `int?` (nullable)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Sir, if it was string then I do not have to add "?" right?, just because string do not get autoinitialized with "Empty String", they retain the NULL values. But in case of integer they by default get auto-initialized to 0.

Comment: A `string` is already nullable, so you would not need to do anything. But because its `int` you need to make it nullable

Comment: @StephenMuecke: That clears my doubt. Because at one more place I had the Optional FK relationship, and it always worked fine. I just now checked. It was "ApplicationUserID" which is of String type (out of the box by framework) so "?"  was not needed  . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change cover letter id assignment in controller

```
CoverLetterId = viewModel.CoverLetterId == 0 ? null : viewModel.CoverLetterId;
```

OR

You can also make

```
public int CoverLetterId { get; set; }
```

change to 
`public int? CoverLetterId { get; set; }` in `ReferralViewModel`.

Then, in controller you would have to use additional check

```
CoverLetterId = viewModel.CoverLetterId.HasValue ? ((viewModel.CoverLetterId.Value == 0) ? null : viewModel.CoverLetterId.Value) : null
```

If you know that you are going to pass 0 from the front-end in HttpPost, and will not let viewModel.CoverLetterId take it's default value, you can just use.

```
CoverLetterId = (viewModel.CoverLetterId.Value == 0) ? null : viewModel.CoverLetterId.Value
```

Comment: You do not need the 'additional check' in you last line of code!

Comment: It wont be '0' (unless its a malicious user) so there is no point

Comment: @Stephen ok, got that. but websites do have malicious users. Added a statement in the answer though incorporating your comment.

Comment: Yes, and if its a malicious user you do not want then saving the data (let an exception be thrown) :)